# Find multiple nested div in Codeception

Tags: html, angularjs, selenium, xpath, codeception

My code is below :

```
$I->see('20.4','//*[@class="container ng-scope"]/div/div/div/div/div[@class="bigNum ng-binding"]');
```

It is working fine but as you can see tthe class is nested into multiple div, want to get rid of so many divs nested.

I tried :

```
$I->see('20.4','//*[@class="container ng-scope"]//*div[@class="bigNum ng-binding"]');
```

Gives me error :

> Cannot find the element.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is just a typo you made when pasting the code here or not.

Your XPath isn't valid.

```
//*[@class="container ng-scope"]//*div[@class="bigNum ng-binding"]
```

should be

```
//*[@class="container ng-scope"]//div[@class="bigNum ng-binding"]
```

Also in your case, CSS selector should be better. `[@class="container ng-scope"]` in XPath will match those two classes in exact order and whitespace, which is probably not what you want.

```
.container.ng-scope .bigNum.ng-binding
```

Comment: @shab: Since you're a new user and never accepted any answers before. Just so you know if this fixes your issue, please accept http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220697. Thanks.